# Is Javascript a good option for providing security within a web app?

Tags: javascript, security

<del>I'm looking to build a database on a server that can be accessed by mobile and desktop applications. 
The idea is when an application is installed on a computer it will contact the server database and register itself, with as little interaction from the user as possible.
I suppose my problem is how can I effectively register a new application, and it's associated computer(s) on the servers database in a secure manner?</del>

<del>Do I have a default user and password for registration purposes?? I'd imagine that's quite insecure.</del>

For example, if I develop a mobile app that interacts with a web app, say like how dropbox or netflix do, is Javascript a good technology to implement security.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by secure a server database?? Security is composed of three domains, CIA confidentiality, integrity, and availability. Depending on the need of your application, server and their subcomponent you should obtain a risk matrix that shuold provide you with guidance in terms of security. Then again, if security is not a real issue and u just want to reduce some known risks that's another story. Anyhow, you SHOULD NOT have default passwords they are an easy way in for hackers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i posted a comment, let me help you a little bit more by providing you with some good securityrelated reading and material.
You have to understand that security has to be tought of from Day 1 or even from day 0; otherwise it become really difficult to add security at the end. You also have to understand that security is not always about coding or buying the most expensive security tools available, security is about hedging the risks and adapt them your need and your capacity.
HEre are below some links to other posts were some security aspects have been discussed

[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345773/how-do-i-make-my-database-connection-secure?rq=1)

[another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429352/what-are-the-minimum-security-precautions-to-put-in-place-for-a-startup?rq=1)

Also, If security is an important aspect of your project, or you expect this project to grow in the future and become a viable one, i would suggest to you to read either ISO 27000 publications (27001 & 27002 in particular) or FIPS (199 & 200). These reading are a little long but they are standards for Information system security. Of course you might not need to follow all aspects of these standards but they can provide good guidance for you. Another known risk assesment solution is OCTAVE, it is also a little bit long but easier to understand and with a great deal of guidance and tools.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on my very vague question

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your question and your tags that you're preparing to deploy a MySQL server instance on a machine that's visible from the public internet. It seems you're planning to have your desktop and mobile apps establish connections, using the MySQL protocol and using well-known MySQL server access credentials (username / password) for the purpose of registering themselves.

**Do Not Do This!**   Seriously.

Instead, create a small web application on a web server than connects to your MySQL database.  Arrange for your client apps to contact your web app with the information needed to register themselves. Then get the web app to carry out whatever MySQL operations are needed for registration.

Put your MySQL server behind a firewall. If you have a data center or a hosting service, this is straightforward and most likely already done.  If you're running your own machine (physical or virtual) set up MySQL so it's not visible from the public internet.

Here's why:

First, it's poor practice to make a database server visible from the public internet. It opens you up to all kinds of badguy tricks, like denial-of-service attacks and attempts to steal your users' data.

Second, you'll have to burden your client applications with MySQL access protocol software. This is bloated compared to using HTTP to post a "register" request.

Third, HTTP is super-lightweight compared to MySQL. Your clients send a simple request and wait for a simple response. Web servers running your app (apache, nginx, IIS, etc) are good at queueing the requests if there are a lot of them.

Fourth, if you do this in a web app you can update the web app if you change your database or business rules.  If you put the MySQL queries in your client apps things get much less flexible.

Good luck. Be careful out there on the internet.

Comment: Thank you for your help with my vague question.